# Quick question on a naive-probability/counting exercise.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

This is exercise 1.23 from Casella and Berger *Statistical inference*.

Two people each toss a fair coin $n$ times.  Find the probability that they will toss the same number of heads.

My reasoning is that the probability of the two sequences of tosses being exactly the same is $(1/4)^n$ now we need to see in how many ways can we permute these two sequences. But I am a bit stuck on how to proceed. How should I do?

Comment: "they will lose the same number of heads"???

Comment: "the probability of the two sequences of tosses being exactly the same is $(1/4)^n$?  Why not $(1/2)^n$?

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/83489/56801

Comment: @KinnisalMountainChicken Oh dear... I edited.