# Two people toss a fair coin $n$ times

Tags: probability

> Two people each toss a fair coin $n$ times. Find the probability that they toss the same number of heads.

My approach: Person $A$ flips a coin $n$ times. Person $B$ flips a coin $n$ times. So we have a total of $2n$ coin flips. Therefore the total number of outcomes of choosing $n$ flips that land heads is $${2n\choose n}$$
Since we flip a coin $n$ times and the coin is fair. The probability person $A$ and person $B$ toss the same number of heads is thus $$\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n {2n\choose n}$$

To be more clear: The probability person $A$ lands heads after $n$ flips is $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ like wise for person $B$ thus we have $$\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n $$

Second approach with helo from Joeb: Let $E_k$ be the event where each person flips exactly $k$ heads we want to calculate $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}P(E_k)$$
Individually we have a probability of $${n\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$ Thus together $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}P(E_k) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n{n\choose k}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n\choose k}{n\choose k} = \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n{2n\choose n} $$

I am just wondering if my reasoning makes sense, I got the correct answer but I just want to know if I explained it clearly enough. I know this is a question that has been posted on here, but I am asking if my approach is correct. The algebra is a bit tricky I didn't solve it myself just used a calculator.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this->http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83489/a-fair-coin-is-tossed-n-times-by-two-people-what-is-the-probability-that-they?rq=1] question.

Comment: I realize it has been posted on here but I am asking a different question

Comment: @Wolfy But you didn't even get the correct answer ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen edited the post, I made a typo mistake it is correct now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me like you are only considering the case where each person flips exactly $n/2$ heads out of $n$ flips.

What if instead you calculated the probability of the event $E_k$ where each person flips exactly $k$ heads ($k=0,1,2,...,n$)? Then you can just take the sum

$\sum_{k=1}^n \mathsf{P}(E_k)$.

Comment: I see, but how do you calculate $P(E_k)$?

Comment: I assume you will have $P(E_k) = {n\choose k}(\frac{1}{2})^k(\frac{1}{2})^{n-k}$? the index $k$ should start at $0$ in this case which is perfectly fine too

Comment: Ah! You are right with the index set starting at $0$. Good catch. And your calculation of the probability $\mathsf{P}(E_k)$ seems correct as well.

Comment: actually it is wrong, we need to square everything for some reason

Comment: I am pretty lost now

Comment: Don't loose faith yet. I apologize, what you calculated $(n\text{C}k)(\frac{1}{2})^k(\frac{1}{2})^{n-k}$ for $\mathsf{P}(E_k)$ is not the probability that both people flip exactly $k$ heads, just one of the people. You need to square your calculation because you need the probability that both people flip $k$ heads. They will do so independently of each other, so that is why you square. Sorry I answered too abruptly.

Comment: right, I think I got it now thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning does not explain the result correctly as you pick $n$ out of $2n$ tosses that produce heads, when actually the number of heads can be $\ne n$ and only the number of heads tossed by $A$ shall be the same as te number of heads tossed by $B$.
Note that of $A$ tosses $k$ heads, this means that $B$ tosses $n-k$ tails. Thus all valid outcome can be produced by picking a subset of $n$ of the $2n$ tosses and assign heads to those ($k$, say) of these picked tosses that are among $A$'s tosses as well as to the $k$ tosses among $B$'s tosses that were *not* picked (and assign tails to the rest). This gives us $2n\choose n$ favorable outcomes, each of which occurs with probability $2^{-2n}$. Hence the result $\frac1{4^n}{2n\choose n}$.